# Automatic Internal Static IP

Tags: dhcp, netplan, ip

Can we set up something like
Automatic Static IP, instead of DHCP?

I don't want to edit netplan every Virtual Machines..
Thank you.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Automatic static IP"?

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`. Although, if you're setting up multiple VMs, DHCP is the right tool to use to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

As a version of APIPA at Microsoft, the AVAHI daemon is used. But in general, self-setting of IPv4 addresses is inappropriate and is a source of trouble. Setting a unique name and unique IP address of the device is a basic task of the new machine administrator and it is not worth bypassing.

If you install dozens of new machines every day, it's worth automating the setup.

Self-setting works well for IPv6 addresses, where you can use link local addresses for basic communication in the same network.

Comment: Is there any way to automate the setup?